# Attack on elasticsearch thwarted?

Tags: security, elasticsearch

I accidentally left elasticsearch exposed to the web.

Somebody tried to execute a search that includes the following script:

```
    String str = \"\";
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(newInputStreamReader(
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(\"/etc/init.d/iptables stop\").getInputStream()));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    while((str = br.readLine()) != null){ sb.append(str); }
    sb.toString();
    "}}}}
```

It looks like they tried to disable the firewall on the machine, and sent back the result of the command.

If found the query because it caused the following Exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: source and source_content_type parameters are required
```

Should I assume the system has been compromised, or is this a sign that the attack has been thwarted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't assume that has been compromised, but you definitely should remove the full access from every host, and after that, dig into the elasticsearch server to search for active connections or signs of any compromised file.

If you use the ELK on AWS they don't store other stuff on the machine, but if is a standalone installation from the ELK stack and if you store other stuff on the server, you should check if everything is still there.